# filtering json from other service and returning it to mobile

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

My use case is to use Play 2.0 WebServices and Jerkson library to modify and return JSON.

```
WS.url(url).get().map { response =>
    Ok(getFields(response.json))
}

def getFields(list: List[String], json: JsValue): Map[String, JsValue] =
(for (key <- list) yield key -> json \ key).toMap
```

1. How to send get with specific ContentType and Application header HTTP request?
2. How to construct an url like: http://example.com/giveMeJson?a=b&c=d=&e=f&g=h&i=j&k=l (a long url expressed nice.
3. Is there any way to remove fields from json? I know only how to get the fields.

Thanks for response and help with my mess :)